Determine which condition made an fstream not read a string?
Reading a std::string from a std::fstream with std::getline() or operator>> sets the same flags (fail and eof) in the following scenarios:

When the string is the last line of the stream.
When the stream is empty.
When the stream is closed.

Is there a way to tell which of those scenarios actually took place?

Please show the current code in which you want to be able to make that distinction. Because this gives me the impression that you are you trying to write a while (!filestream.eof()) loop. Read this if you do : fistream not reading eof character

You can use is_open to check if the steam is open, you'll have to check how many lines you've read to see if the steam is empty

Reading the last element does not set either flag.

You might get eof when the file ends, but the read will not fail if there was something to read before that. Check the size of the string.

Why do you want to read from a closed stream in the first place?

(fail and eof) in the following scenarios: - When the string is the last line of the stream. No, if it was the last line but the line was successfully read, fail is not set. fail means that no result was produced. The next reading operation after reaching the end will cause fail and eof

"After the last line" and "stream is empty" are the same case, i.e. 0 characters remaining. To tell them apart, keep track of how much you've already read.

No flags are set on reading the last line of a stream - end of file will be encountered on a subsequent read. If the stream is "empty", the first attempt at reading will also reach end of file, and there is no way to distinguish between end of file encountered immediately, or end of file encountered after reading data, unless your program keeps track of how much it has read.      Your code also should not try to read from a closed stream (either use yourstream.is_open() to check if the stream has an associated file BEFORE reading, or only read from streams you KNOW are open).

Do you have any specific case that requires distinguishing between "stream was initially empty" and "I have reached end of (non-empty) stream"? Or distinguishing between "stream is empty" and "stream failed to open" such that you cannot check is_open before reading?

@BoP -- to be clear, you will not get eof unless the read failed because it hit the end of the file. The end of file marks the end of the input, and reading up to the end is not a failure.
